# Dell Precision 3520 Compatibility with 18.04

Tags: 18.04, dell, hardware

The Precision 3520 is certified for 16.04, but I can't find any info anywhere that indicates whether there are any known problems with this model working with 18.04.  I would like to upgrade, but can't risk not having my computer available for work.

I am looking for either any trusted-source info online about known issues, or info anyone can provide regarding your experience upgrading this model to 18.04.
TIA

Comment: I can, and I will.  But I prefer not to trust anything done by only one person, including myself.  If possible, I'd like others' experience/info as well.

Comment: Hmmm. I think that should be part of the question.